# i want to factory reset my PC, i copied important files to my onedrive

Tags: onedrive

the files are currently still syncing to onedrive. do I need to wait for the sync to finish before i start resetting my PC? or is it ok to just reset now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the sync is complete. Otherwise you will erase the files that have not been uploaded. (Unless the factory reset supports saving user data as some vendors do).

As a safety, wait until the files are done uploading to OneDrive first.